# Input:checked doesn't work in IE9

Tags: javascript, radio-button, internet-explorer-9

I made a simple modal that adds a series of records into some tables. 
Before submitting the values I ask the user to check a radio to confirm the action. 
When the radio is checked the submit button becomes clickable. 
This works fine almost in every browser except for IE9 (and previous): in this browser I have to check the radio and then click on a blank point into the modal and only then the submit button becomes clickable. 
This is a screenshot of the modal: 
[image]

And this is the portion of the code interested:

```
 function checkAcconsento() {
    var acconsento = document.querySelector('input[name=acconsento]:checked').value;
    if (acconsento == 'S') {
        document.getElementById('btn_ins_corso').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('btn_ins_corso').className = "btn_normale";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('btn_ins_corso').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('btn_ins_corso').className = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You an try the following, depending on different version of Jquery and browser

```
$('#element').is(':checked');
$('#element').attr('checked');
```